# Shell script & param file(s) for deployment across multiple environments

Tags: linux, bash, shell, parameters, reusability

I have a shell script that installs a particular software on an Azure VM. Say, it is install_software.sh.

There are environment specific parameters defined in a .param file. For example,

```
INSTALLATION_PATH=XYZ
INSTALLER_LOCATION=ABC
```

I plan to do this:

1. Create 3 param files specific to DEV, QA, PROD environments
2. Load all the 3 files from GitHub into the VM
3. Accept environment name as an argument while executing the script, example:

   sh install_software.sh DEV
4. Check if $1 of the executed command is DEV, and EXPORT from DEV .param file.

Now, do you think this is a good approach? Or, is there any smarter approach. Appreciate if I can be pointed to any sample code snippets too. Thank you very much.

Comment: remove the leading `$` so that `$INSTALLATION_PATH=XYZ` becomes `INSTALLATION_PATH=XYZ` or `export INSTALLATION_PATH=XYZ`; 3x param files is fine; another option is to pull everything into a single param file with some `if/then` or `case` logic to set the appropriate variables

Comment: Depending on how many parameters you have, and how many of them are the same for each environment, you may wish to split them into 4 files. One containing only the parameters that are common to all three environments, and the others containing only the parameters that differ between environments. It is better to put them in files as you suggest, rather than inside `if...; then...fi` statements in your script because you can then edit the parameters without having to edit the script file.